# How to Implement Kiosk Mode in a Flutter Windows Application?

Tags: windows, flutter

I am currently developing an application for kiosk devices. For this, I'm working with a Windows output. However, during some operations like scrolling, the Windows taskbar may appear, or Windows functionalities might get triggered unintentionally.

On platforms like Android and iOS, there are packages like 'kiosk_mode' to handle this situation, but they lack support for Windows. I'm looking for a similar solution that can work on Windows.

Has anyone encountered this issue before and found a solution to implement kiosk mode in a Windows application effectively? Any advice, sample code or resources would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: run in full screen mode ?

Answer (score 0):

For implementing kiosk mode in your Flutter Windows application, I recommend exploring the [window_manager](https://pub.dev/packages/window_manager) project. This project is specifically designed to provide comprehensive support for essential kiosk mode features. It includes functionalities like fullscreen mode, always-on-top behavior, hidden launch at startup, and a frameless UI to create a seamless kiosk experience.

Moreover, the development [team](https://leanflutter.org/) behind the 'window_manager' project has also developed other valuable libraries that can enhance your kiosk setup. For instance, you might find [launch_at_startup](https://pub.dev/packages/launch_at_startup) and [hotkey_manager](https://pub.dev/packages/hotkey_manager) particularly relevant.